# Sql query to select several items from a another table in relation to values on a single row of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, where-clause

```
orderTb: **id_order** **qty** **id_user** **updatedby**
           1             5         2            1

userTb:  **id** **name**
           1      paul
           2      mark
```

These are my two tables, wish do a mysql query to return: id_order,qty,id_user as name1 and updatedby as name2. I've tried this query but not working:

```
select orderTb.id_order,orderTb.qty,userTb.name as name1,userTb.name as Name2 
from orderTb,userTb where orderTb.id_user=userTb.id OR 
orderTb.updatedby=userTb.id
```

Comment: *not working* is not an error description. Share the expected result and the result you get

Comment: Okay, next time I'll make sure to display error. Thanks for the remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.

```
SELECT o.id_order, o.qty, u1.name as name1, u2.name as name2 
FROM orderTb o
INNER JOIN userTb u1 ON u1.id=o.id_user
INNER JOIN userTb u2 ON u2.id=o.updatedby;
```

See the demo here: [**DB-Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=576b9c1884edd43069aa5c0aad82b683)

Answer (score 0):

You have to join `userTb` twice:

```
select orderTb.id_order,orderTb.qty,user.name as name1,userUpdate.name as Name2 
from orderTb user join userTb on orderTb.id_user=user.id 
join userTb userUpdate on orderTb.updatedby=userUpdate.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [JOIN clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) in order to achieve that.

You will need 2 JOIN clauses to `userTb`: one to link the `id_user` column with a `userTb` that we'll call `userTb1`, one to link the `updatedby` column with another `userTb` that we'll call `userTb2`:

```
SELECT orderTb.id_order, orderTb.qty, userTb1.name AS name1, userTb2.name AS Name2
FROM orderTb
INNER JOIN userTb userTb1 ON orderTb.id_user = userTb1.id
INNER JOIN userTb userTb2 ON orderTb.updatedby= userTb2.id
```